# Type 'Error' provides no match for the signature '(this: Observable<{}>, subscriber: Subscriber<{}>): TeardownLogic'

Tags: angular

I had angular 5.2.11, but today I updated it to 6, so when I try to build, I got an error
says :

> TS2345: Argument of type `Error` is not assignable to parameter of type `(this: Observable<{}>, subscriber: Subscriber<{}>) => TeardownLogic`.   Type `Error` provides no match for the signature `(this: Observable<{}>, subscriber: Subscriber<{}>): TeardownLogic`.

```
serviceInvoke<R,B>(baseUrl: string, relativeUrl: string, requestMethod: RequestMethod, params: {
  [key: string]: any | any[]
}, body ? : B): Observable<R> {
  const requestOptionsArgs = {
    method: requestMethod,
    params: params,
    body: body
  };
  return this.httpClient.request(baseUrl + relativeUrl, requestOptionsArgs)
    .pipe(
      map((response: Response) => response.json()),
      catchError((httpErrorResponse: Response) => new ErrorObservable(this.getError(httpErrorResponse)))
    );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQYKW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you don't really need to `map` and convert `response` to JSON explicitly by calling `response.json()` when using `HttpClient`.

That was only required when using `Http`.

Try getting rid of that. Something like this:

```
serviceInvoke<R,B>(
  baseUrl: string, 
  relativeUrl: string, 
  requestMethod: RequestMethod, 
  params: { [key: string]: any | any[] }, 
  body?: B
): Observable<R> {
  const requestOptionsArgs = {
    method: requestMethod,
    params: params,
    body: body
  };

  return this.httpClient.request(baseUrl + relativeUrl, requestOptionsArgs)
    .pipe(
      catchError((httpErrorResponse: Response) => new ErrorObservable(this.getError(httpErrorResponse)))
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried it but still same issue, I added a snapshot so you might have better view.

Comment: Can you replicate this on a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)? It's really hard to understand the whole flow without actually getting to see what we're getting in the response and what are these other pieces in the code.

Just a minimal replicate would do.

Comment: To be honest, I am new in angular world and the system is complicated, I am not sure how I can replicate that.

Answer (score 1):

You could face this error if you tried to create a new observable in the following way.

```
new Observable(new Error)
```

The correct way is

```
new Observable(observer => observer.next(new Error))
```